# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end

Tags: php

EDIT: My client gave me wrong details here is correct code
This is part of the area which gives the problem. Full code is too large but available here
http://pastebin.com/9506yzGh
Here is what stumps me, on my VM(testing ground) this code works!! proof of that 
http://socialneko.koding.com/ Now however on the godaddy hosting it does not. http://socialneko.com/

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /home/content/21/11408921/html/index.php on line 297

```
  <?php
$ads = array(
"<a href='http://3ds-explore.com'><img src='http://puu.sh/391aC.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://socialpixel.heliohost.org'><img src='/image/socialpixel.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://strike.koding.com'>DSiStrike</a>",
"<a href='http://3dsar7.koding.com'><img src='/image/remixed.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://l09.heliohost.org'><img src='/image/l09.png'></a>"
);

print_r($ads[array_rand($ads)]);
?></center>

<span style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:180px;font-size:10px;color:gray;letter-spacing:-1px;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;">
<?php echo $database->getNumMembers(); ?> members and growing!
</span>

<br><center><a href="http://mobile.twitter.com/sosharuneko"><img src="/image/follow.png"></a></center><br>

<?php include("footer.php"); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

footer.php:

```
<hr>
<div class="footer" style="font-size:10px;color:grey"> <center>
    Total members: <?php echo $database->getNumMembers(); ?><br>
    Newcomer: <?php
        $getnewcomer = mysqli_query(db(), "SELECT username FROM users ORDER BY id DESC");
        $newcomer = mysqli_fetch_row($getnewcomer);
        if($session->logged_in){
            echo "<a href='/user/".strtolower($newcomer[0])."'>$newcomer[0]</a>";
        } else {
            echo $newcomer[0];
        }
    ?>
    <p> <div class="copyright"> This website is &copy;2012-2013 SocialNeko.<br> All rights reserved.<p> About :: <a href="/guide/terms.php">Terms</a></center> </div><p>
</div>
```

db() function

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0){
die("<p><b>It looks like we can't connect to the database.</b><br>A team of highly trained monkeys has been dispatched to deal with this situation.<p>If you see them, show them this information:<br>[" . $db->connect_error . "]<br>Refreshing in 8 seconds. <meta http-equiv='REFRESH' content='8;url='>");
//die('Unable to connect to database ');
}

function db()
{
global $db;
global $host;
global $db_username;
global $db_pass;
global $db_name;
if (!$db) {
$db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
}

return $db;
}
```

Comment: See sidebar, it having lots of similar question.

Comment: I see, hmm. Very frustrating.

Comment: What's inside footer.php?

Comment: @Jordan
http://pastebin.com/mPvmg15j

Comment: This is frequently characteristic of having an unclosed bracket or parenthesis somewhere. Good luck searching 300 lines of code!

Comment: @MikeW but it works on my koding.com VM?

Sorry about that, I updated it.

Comment: And you're absolutely sure, based on timestamps and file sizes/hashes that you have the exact same code on production that you have in your development VM?

Comment: @zloctb    connection function

Comment: @Jordan yes
Edit: LEt me check to be 100%

Comment: The problem source is the lack of code intendation and heavy mixing of php and html sections. Use a proper IDE.

Comment: Why don't you load all the files into a nice IDE or text editor with syntax hilighting and find the unmatched bracket? OR Make sure the file is completely uploaded to the server, sometimes when I use FTP only part of the file uploads and I get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Go Daddy has php short tag turned off by default - `short_open_tag = off`.

So lines 78

```
<? }else{ ?>
```

80

```
<? } ?>
```

92

```
<? } ?>
```

286

```
<? }else{ ?>
```

290

```
<? } ?>
```

are not parsing.

The best thing to do is to change them all to `<?php`.

You could also change `short_open_tag = on` in your php.ini, or `<?php ini_set(‘short_open_tag’,’1′); ?>` at the top of your page, but not recommended.

Comment: +1 Yes, issue is with short tag, @Abu replace `<?` with `<?php`

Comment: Whats sucks is I got downvoted for this. :l

Answer (score 1):

This is just a standard 'elbow grease' debugging problem: The line number is usually useless with this error in my experience as it gives the EOF ln # and per one of the comments it is usually an unclosed bracket, paren, etc.

One hacky, but productive, way that I have found is to drop in an `exit;` starting with the first block of code in the script, and if it executes up to that point with out an error, remove `exit;` from that point, and put it further down. Eventually you should hit your error vs. line by line debugging.

i.e.:

```
 <?php
$ads = array(
"<a href='http://3ds-explore.com'><img src='http://puu.sh/391aC.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://socialpixel.heliohost.org'><img src='/image/socialpixel.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://strike.koding.com'>DSiStrike</a>",
"<a href='http://3dsar7.koding.com'><img src='/image/remixed.png'></a>",
"<a href='http://l09.heliohost.org'><img src='/image/l09.png'></a>"
);

// Start Cutoff: 1st try to make sure code is executing up to this point:
exit;
// End Cut Off -- if it executed up to here - move this cutoff block further down, 
// until you can approximate where the error is occuring


print_r($ads[array_rand($ads)]);
?></center>

<span style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:180px;font-size:10px;color:gray;letter-spacing:-1px;-webkit-touch-callout: none;-webkit-user-select: none;-khtml-user-select: none;-moz-user-select: none;-ms-user-select: none;user-select: none;">
<?php echo $database->getNumMembers(); ?> members and growing!
</span>
```

Comment: Well I tried it. xD
And this is what I get. Does that mean my problem is above?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_EXIT, expecting ')' in /home/content/21/11408921/html/index.php on line 279